# Inverse of a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

How can one show that the inverse of the transformation $$x=y+h(y)$$ $x$,$y$ in $n$ dimensional real space and $h$ is an $r$-th degree homogeneous polynomial in $y$ has an inverse at $0$ in $n$ dimensional real space is of the form $$y=x-h(x)+O(|X|)$$ where $O(|X|)$  is raised to the power of $r+1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It helps to share any thoughts or work you have done in order for responders to provide better guidance. Regards

Answer (score 1):

since y is a polynomial of degree $r$ i.e $y^r$ hence

$$\begin{align}
x &= y+ y^r\\
 &= -1/4 + 1/4 + y + y^r\\
 &= -1/4 +  (y^(r-1) + 1/2)^2
\end{align}$$

hence 
$1/4 + x = (y^(r-1) + 1/2)^2 $
taking square root of both sides

$$(1/4 + x)^1/2 = y^(r-1) + 1/2$$

expanding the left hand side using Maclaurin's series
$$1/2 + x -x^2 + 2x^3 + ...= y^(r-1) + 1/2$$
therefore 
$$y^(r-1) = x -x^2 + 2x^3$$
since r is greater than or equal to 2,hence
$$y^(2-1) = x -x^2 + 2x^3$$

$$y = x -x^2 + 2x^3$$

hence $$y = x -x^2 + 0(|X|)^(r+1)$$